# HtmlUnit can't find forms on website

Tags: java, forms, htmlunit

At the following website I try to access the login and password forms with HtmlUnit: https://zof.interreport.com/diveport#

However this very simple javascript returns an empty list [].

```
void homePage() throws Exception{

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://zof.interreport.com/diveport#");
    System.out.println(page.getForms());
}
```

So somehow HtmlUnit doesn't recognize the forms on the page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

At first: you only show some java code but you talk about javascript - is there anything missing?

Regarding the form. The page you are trying to test is one of these pages that doing some work on the client side. This implies, that after the page is loaded, the real page/dom is created inside your browser by invoking javascript. When using HtmlUnit you have to take care of that. In simple cases it is sufficient to wait for the javacript to be processed.

This code works for me:

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://zof.interreport.com/diveport#");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
    System.out.println(page.getForms());
```

Take care to use the latest SNAPSHOT build of HtmlUnit.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. However, only one form is found. Can you tell me how to get access to the login and password fields and the log on button?

Comment: Use Firebug to inspect the page/dom structure and than use the HtmlUnit API (start here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html)

Comment: Ah too bad you don't know either. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Solved this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on that API but here is the trick

1. Open same page in your browser by disabling the JavaScript. It is not working.

   - This means the page loading its content using some JavaScript dom operations.
   - If you can not get html here there must be some way out in API you are using.
2. Check with the HtmlUnit api documentation. The class [JAVADOC](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#executeJavaScript(java.lang.String))

   - There is method

   public ScriptResult executeJavaScript(String sourceCode)

The key here is if API you are using will not execute the JavaScript on its won and you have to code for it.