# Navigating to javascript form using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

## Overview

I have successfully been using HtmlUnit to navigate BoardGameGeek and execute tasks (e.g. send GeekMail). Recently they changed their login from a normal webpage to a *javascript-generated form*, and now I just can't seem to access the login form using HtmlUnit no matter what I try, including:

- Adding a WebWindowListener.
- Waiting for javascript to complete with `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(JAVASCRIPT_PAUSE)` or `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(JAVASCRIPT_PAUSE)`.
- Listing all windows (0) and forms (1).
- Printing XML for the current HtmlPage and all HtmlForms.

Of course I want a general understanding beyond this specific webpage / javascript code, but I give this specific concrete example since the other StackOverflow questions I looked at didn't help in this particular situation (so maybe there is something unique here?).

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Use your browser to navigate to https://boardgamegeek.com/geekmail/compose?touser=FakeUserName (any name will suffice).
2. As long as you are not logged in to BoardGameGeek, you will then see a pop-up window titled "Sign in" with text inputs "Username" and "Password".
3. If you View Page Source, you will see that the form is generated by javascript (https://cf.geekdo-static.com/frontend/main-es2015.aeff0e4f13bcecc7eb55.js or https://cf.geekdo-static.com/frontend/main-es5.aeff0e4f13bcecc7eb55.js). As far as I can tell, the created form has no name / id that I can use to access it. Even if it did, I do not seem to be able to view it within HtmlUnit (i.e. "Sign up" never appears when I print XML, whether for HtmlPage or HtmlForm).

## Existing code

Here is my current version of the code with multiple attempts made to diagnose the problem / extract some useful information:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
...
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GeekMailSender {
    ...

    // Static variable to track all website windows.
    private final static LinkedList<WebWindow> websiteWindows = new LinkedList<WebWindow>();
    
    // Inner-class to listen for new (i.e. pop-up) windows.
    static class GeekMailWindowListener implements WebWindowListener {
        public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {}
        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {}
        public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) {
            GeekMailSender.websiteWindows.add(event.getWebWindow());
        }
    }

    // Method to actually send GeekMail by navigating the BGG website.
    public static void sendGeekMail(...) {
        ...
        try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
            // Track creation of new (i.e. pop-up) windows.
            websiteWindows.clear();
            webClient.addWebWindowListener(new GeekMailWindowListener());
            
            // Try to access the GeekMail page.
            HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("https://boardgamegeek.com/geekmail/compose?touser=FakeUserName");
            String pageTitle = currentPage.getTitleText();
            System.out.println(pageTitle);  // BoardGameGeek
            
            // We may need to login first.
            if (!pageTitle.contains("GeekMail")) {
                // Need to wait for javascript to complete, otherwise no forms are available.
                webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(JAVASCRIPT_PAUSE);
                // No difference if use webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(JAVASCRIPT_PAUSE);

                // Unfortunately the only form found is the top-right Search form on BoardGameGeek.
                if (currentPage.getForms().isEmpty()) {
                    // This does NOT happen.
                    System.out.println("WARNING! No form found, even after waiting for javascript!");
                    return;
                }

                // We don't find any windows at all... this confuses me.
                if (websiteWindows.isEmpty()) {
                    // This does happen :(
                    System.out.println("WARNING! No windows found even after waiting for javascript!");
                }

                // Additional printing does not reveal where the form is.
                // For instance, searching the XML for "Sign up" yields no results.
                System.out.println(currentPage.asXml());
                
                // And printing the one form we can access reveals it is just the Search form.
                System.out.println(currentPage.getForms().size());  // 1
                final HtmlForm loginForm = currentPage.getForms().get(0);
                System.out.println(loginForm.asXml());
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

## References

In trying to solve this, I have checked the following references (among many others):

- https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/gettingStarted.html
- [HtmlUnit can't find forms on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117026/htmlunit-cant-find-forms-on-website)
- [Locating a pop up window with HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528410/locating-a-pop-up-window-with-htmlunit)
- https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/mailman/message/20356348/
- https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener.html

Nevertheless, I seem unable to locate the desired form. Any help would be much appreciated!

## Updates

1. Added this issue to github as https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/401. Also some minor formatting fixes above.
2. Was [given a workaround on BoardGameGeek forums](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2751648/login-form-renamed), specifically using HTML POST to a different url. So my issue with HtmlUnit remains unsolved, but at least the functionality of my website has been restored.

Comment: Can you please copy this as a HtmlUnit issue to remind me to have a look.

Comment: @RBRi: Do you mean here: https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/submittingBugs.html?

Comment: simply open a new issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit and c&p all the details from this.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/401. Thanks for taking a look!